# Electron exec launching multiple processes

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm creating an electron application that launches a .exe file. I use exec to do so, as it needs special arguments. In the renderer I have a button that launches it, If i click that button multiple times, it's going to execute the .exe file multiple times, so if i click it for the second time, it will launch 2 .exe files. This is my code in the renderer:

```
$(".buttonJSMain").click(function() {
    ipcRenderer.send("download-lc");

    ipcRenderer.on("downloaded-lc", (event) => {
        var authType = 'authType';
        var username = 'username';
        var password = 'password';
        var memory = 'memory';

        var arguments = authType + " " + username + " " + password + " " + memory;
        ipcRenderer.send('run', arguments);
    });
})
```

This is my code in the main thread:

```
ipcMain.on('run', (event, arguments) => {
  var child = require('child_process').execFile;
  var args = arguments;

  try {
    exec("file.exe " + arguments, (error, stdout, stderr);
  } catch {
    console.log('Couldn\'t start')
  }
})
```

How could i make it so that it only launches the file one time?

Comment: Hi, you appear to have not asked a question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. Thought it was clear.

Comment: What do you mean by one time?, one time forever,  one time when the app is loaded, or one time within a certain amount of time.  If it's just 1 time when app is loaded, a simple global boolean flag should work.

Comment: I mean when the user clicks the button that should launch the file

Comment: Well, `exec("file.exe " + arguments, (error, stdout, stderr);` is not particularly valid JavaScript. Either the opening `(` after `arguments` is erroneous or you wanted to define a function but didn't. Probably the latter, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

Use a global boolean flag as stated in the comments.

```
let running = false // global flag

ipcMain.on('run', (event, arguments) => {
  var child = require('child_process').execFile;
  var args = arguments;

  try {
    if ( running === false ) { // no instance is running
      running = true; // state you are about to run
      exec("file.exe " + arguments, (error, stdout, stderr);
      running = false; // let others to run
    }
    else {
      console.log("Another instance is running");
    }
  } catch {
    running = false
    console.log('Couldn\'t start')
  }
})
```